# Set up a different index document per directory with S3 static website hosting

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3

I am using S3 static website hosting, and trying to get the following redirects to work:

```
example.com --> example.com/index.html
example.com/foo --> example.com/foo/foo.html
example.com/bar --> example.com/bar/bar.html
etc.
```

I can only set one 'index document' value for the entire bucket, and that's 'index.html' at the moment. But then, with foo, I can't have a different "default" document.

I would like to avoid having a bunch of 'index.html', as it becomes really annoying to work on editing those files, always wondering which is which, because they all have the same names. Hence the above redirect scheme.

It seems I can't use the xml-format redirect rules of S3 static website hosting, as you run into an infinite recursion: if one redirects URLS with the prefix 'foo' into 'foo/foo.html', the redirect is applied again, and you get foo/foo/foo.html' etc.

One other option would be a redirect with an empty index.html set up in the bucket itself using a redirect metadata entry on the index.html file to go to foo.html. But that would defeat my goal of keeping it simple and I would still have to add all those files called 'index.html' and setup a bunch of redirects.

Without a better option, I'll simply work with a bunch of index.html files and suck it up. But if there is a way out, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear, but I explained why: when editing the files, all those html files are named the same, and I find it very frustrating to have 5 tabs all called index.html, and never know which one has which.